# Dell R640 NVMe backplane connectors

Tags: dell-poweredge

I am trying to figure out the R640 NVMe backplane.
[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeuNt.jpg). The goal is to use the NVMe drives in front bays and use HBA to connect to external enclosure.
So I am trying to figure out what part numbers do I need and how to make any sense out of this layout on Dell support site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN5ri.jpg

Or in general, is there a "field service manual" for the R640, where I can find list of supported configurations and part numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: Friendly heads up, I wasn't the downvote, but on StackExchange you will likely be heavily downvoted if you ask things that are easily Google'd. If you punch "Dell R640 field service module" into Google it is on the first page of results - same with the technical guide. Anytime I write a Stack Exchange question I do a scan of the existing questions and easy search results to avoid that. Hope that helps you out navigating the new stack exchange user experience which can be a bit brutal.

Answer (score 1):

(Obligatory legal note: I work for Dell)

The supported configs are [here](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/poweredge-r640/per640_ism_pub/supported-configurations-for-poweredge-r640?guid=guid-f1f49a0d-6e9f-4532-9da3-75ed11523f3a&lang=en-us). Dell builds its own backplanes so barring buying something on eBay or reverse engineering the board and buying the corresponding parts, you're not likely to modify it. Though that would be an interesting science project.

[Field Service Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/poweredge-r640/per640_ism_pub/dell-emc-poweredge-r640-overview)

[Technical Guide](https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/us/PowerEdge-R640-Technical-Guide.pdf)

It looks like you have the all NVMe backplane since none of the SAS connections are hooked up. I'm not sure what you mean by HBA for external enclosure - that shouldn't require you to mess with the backplane. You usually use a PCIe card connected to an external enclosure for that.